# White spaces around image inside a button tag?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a button tag on a webpage and inside of it an image, you can see it below:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnLogin">
   <img src="images/login.png" />
</button>
```

But in browser, there are some white spaces around the image. You can see it on an image below. I marked the image with red frame.

[image]

How can i remove these white spaces around the image? This design came from a designer and i have no time to make him change this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following style to your button and image

```
<button runat="server" id="btnLogin" style="padding:0; width:auto; height:auto">
     <img src="images/login.png" style="margin:0; padding:0" /> 
</button>
```

You can also set the width and the height of the button to be exactly the same as the image

Comment: Adding "margin" and "padding" to image doesnt do any change.Compare my answer fiddle and the fiddle with margin and padding to image http://jsfiddle.net/7Dw7q/2/ .You will see no change

Comment: How do you know that? Have you seen what css styles his page elements are inheriting?

Comment: Obviously what I'm trying to do is reset every box-related css style that his button and image may have inherited

Comment: Seeing his image i dont think he has applied any css to the button element or image within it

Comment: Yeah? I must say you have magnificent eye mate. Good stuff!

Comment: Thank you Leo, that works. I don't know what is the issue but as @Zword said, Margin and Padding don't do anything in image tag on my page. I just added padding,width and height inside button tag's style attribute. Anyway, thank you so much again :)

Comment: @ErdemGundogdu margin and padding is required if you have applied CSS to button or image within it.Otherwise no margin and padding is required.

Comment: @Zword I know basic CSS but you can be sure that what you just said will always keep in my mind from this moment :) Thank you !!!

Comment: @Zword I'm still curious to know how you can assume that his page wasn't setting the margin or padding through inline styles or simply through a style sheets link on the page...you must really have some super natural powers mate lol

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS:

```
#btnLogin{
    border-width:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

See this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Dw7q/1/

If you notice closely ,in the above fiddle it still shows a light silver border around.If you want to remove that too the add this CSS to the above:

```
#btnLogin img{
    margin:-2px;
}
```

Output: http://jsfiddle.net/7Dw7q/3/

Comment: This is assuming the image doesn't have any margin specified somewhere else or that the button doesn't have any width and/or height specified

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button runat="server" id="btnLogin" style="border-width: 0px;">
    <img src="images/login.png" style="border-width: 0px;" />
</button>
```

EDIT: border-size does not existst

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your CSS.

```
padding:0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `input` tag to create a button with an image.
It works like a `button` tag in a form.

```
<input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/EJ3W1KM.jpg" />
```

You can play with a demo on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzi/qZUWp/).

Cheers,
Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer to this question is; The img is within a button. That makes it so there's a physical space after the `<img/>` tag of the image.

The img tag should be bordering the button tag, like so;

```
<button runat="server" id="btnLogin" style="border-width: 0px;"><img src="images/login.png" style="border-width: 0px;" /></button>
```

The whitespace in between actually gets rendered because you're withing a `button` element. Also, images do have such bugs sometimes and in those cases you can just give them a `display:block;`.

Please [see this article](https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block) for more ways of preventing this from happening to you!